# Chrome 58 Not secure Data in URL

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The recent upgrade to Chrome 58 has caused an issue.  When Selenium launches an instance of Chrome it doesn't navigate to the initial URL like it did with Chrome 57.   Now when Chrome is launched via Selenium we get this issue:

[image: ChromeNotSecureData]

It just hangs right there and won't move.  Has anyone else found a workaround for this?

If I downgrade back to Chrome 57... no issues what-so-ever!  Unfortunately we need to use 58 now.

I have several nodes in my grid and this occurs on every single one of them.  I thought maybe it was a group policy or something but the fact that it runs perfectly on 57 makes no sense to me.

** Update: another issue that I'm having is that it often takes two or three attempts at opening the browser before it finally launches.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but Is your version of chromedriver up to date? It says the latest release, 2.29, 
 works with Chrome 58. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: Yep, that was the first thing I tried.  We're running 2.29.

Comment: Can you perform a quick check if the issue occurs with Grid configuration only? I'm sure the latest version of Selenium, ChromeDriver & Chrome works just fine for me in regular automation.

Answer (score 3):

Add the **--enable-automation** argument to your webdriver.  By default, Chrome 58 requires https and it will not display pages that cannot handle this, the enable-automation lets the browser know the webdriver is steering and it is safe to display the page.